# How can we compare graph clustering results to find similar genes in a Protein-Protein Interaction Network?

Tags: graph, cluster-analysis, bioinformatics, similarity

Our goal is to find similar genes in a ppi network dataset which is in the form of a weighted edgelist. After we use graph clustering algorithms how do we measure similarities of these clusters?

A sample row of our dataset:

```
Gene1 Gene2 Weight
10021 23416 0.1365
10040 57679 0.1244
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Adjusted rand index, Jaccard similarity, completeness, homogeneity, these are all measures that should give an idea of cluster similarity. They are all implemented in [scipy](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/clustering.html#clustering-performance-evaluation).

If your number of cluster isn't too high, say no higher than 20, I am a big fan of making a [contingency matrix](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/clustering.html#contingency-matrix) for analyzing two different clustering results.

Ofcourse you won't have a ground truth in these scenarios, but you can still use all above mentioned metrics to find similarity between results.